# My Ajax Form Submission script isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've got all my form areas setup correctly and my Javascript received them. I've tested this with "alert", but for some reason, I don't know why, my form either isn't submitting or the PHP is wrong.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
//Main Content
var ed = tinyMCE.get('content');
var doc = document.getElementById("docid").value;
//Post Area
ed.setProgressState(1); // Show progress
$.ajax({             
type: 'POST',
data: {'docid':document.getElementById("docid").value, 'content':tinyMCE.get('content').getContent()},
url: 'save.php',
success: function () {
   ed.setProgressState(0);
   $("#notice").fadeIn("slow").fadeOut(3000);
}
});

return false;
```

Here's `save.php`:

```
$id = $_POST['docid'];
$cn = $_POST['content'];
require_once("scripts/php/rq/connect.docs.php");
mysqli_query=($con, "UPDATE wordit_documents SET main_document='".$cn."' WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Comment: Remove the `=` in `mysqli_query=($con` or do `$query = mysqli_query($con...` that's one main issue here.

Comment: `"I don't know why, my form either isn't submitting or the PHP is wrong."` I think a web developer should be able to at least tell whether the data arrives correctly at the server or not, and what error PHP gives, if any. Now it could be anywhere from an error in Javascript to a typo in a query, or maybe even a couple of those.

Comment: Why are you using window.document.getElementById when you could use $("#id") ? But anyway. How does your html look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found The Problem it was because of an "=" In The mysqli_query, Thanks For Answers

Answer (score 0):

**1. ensure client is sending correct data.**

Try using the [inspector](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) in Google Chrome, and activate the network tab.

[image]

Under form data you can see the data sent to the server (the picture shows the text of this answer being sent to stackoverflow to be saved as a draft.).

If not:

Make sure your script is wrapped in a jQuery.ready function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // goes in here
});
```

Test the output of

```
console.log(document.getElementById("docid"));
console.log(tinyMCE.get('content'));
console.log(tinyMCE.get('content').getContent());
```